# Is it possible to select a target platform from within a run configuration?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, run-configuration, target-platform

I'm using Eclipse RCP 2021-9 (can't update because the project is based on this specific version)

Let's say I have 2 target platforms and 2 run configurations in my RCP workspace. I'd like the run config 1 to run with TP 1 and the run config 2 to run with TP 2.

Is it possible ? If so, how would I do that ?

I looked into the run configuration dialog and couldn't find anything related to the target platform.

Thanks

Comment: Not that I know off. You can only select which features (or plug-ins) are enabled. What is so release specific that you have to stick with 2021-09? You should normally be able to use the current Eclipse release and specify an older target platform.

Comment: That's just because I'm not in charge and the people responsible chose to stick to this version. But I don't think any recent version has tackled this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge this is not possible.

You should either create a combined Target Platform (Oomph's targlets may be of help but they have their own limitations). Or use 2 different Eclipse instances (possibly pointing at the same sources, just make sure to refresh your workspace etc. when needed).

Comment: Yes it might be the only solution for the moment. Thanks